# How to add text to last created file in angularjs table based on date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data that i am displaying in table using ng-repeat, I want to display text "currently recording" with most recent file created. `fileDate` is file created date from server.

main.html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="file in data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
    <td>{{file.filename}}<span ng-show="">currently recording</span></td>
    <td>{{file.fileDate |date : "dd.MM.y"}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadServerFile(file.filename)">download</button></td>
</tr>
```

data

```
[ { fileDate: Thu Aug 11 2016 09:59:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    filename: 'server.log' },
  { fileDate: Wed Aug 10 2016 10:10:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    filename: 'server1.log' },
  { fileDate: Tue Aug 30 2016 10:48:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    filename: 'server2.log' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can turn your dates in your list to javascript date objects then add an additional filter or only filter by that. property. Then use that to display by most recent, if I understand exactly what you want.